# Rotating about a vector, Blueprints Unreal Engine 4

Tags: rotation, game-physics, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have a problem where I want to rotate an Actor about an arbitrary vector, I wonder if there's a standard way of using Blueprints to achieve that, in case I have the vector's coordinates. I didn't find anything useful online.

One more smaller issue I encountered, regarding the extraction of that vector:
Is there a way to extract world coordinates of some key-points of an Actor using Blueprints or the UE4 interface?

For example, given a door frame which is rotated 5 degrees around the X axis, can I extract the world coordinates of one of its corners using simple tools such as Blueprints or the interface?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is not an answerable question. What would a good answer for this look like? Links to other websites or tutorials? Sample code? A long answer discussing the various points and side effects?

Comment: Blueprints is more a classification than "narrowing it down", because a C++ answer in most cases can be translated (sometimes in a pretty convoluted way) to blueprints. The problem here is the interpretation, which should come from the question itself and not by comments as this is actually not a discussion per se. Some images, drawings or examples of Desired/Expected output will help. As long as it is open to interpretation, the answers might vary and prove highly unuseful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are rotating an actor (in this case, by your example that actor should be the door) you can take multiple approaches, but I'll list only three:

**Option 1**

First, define a Socket in the door mesh, in the position you want to obtain. Then, get its current position with a `GetSocketLocation` node.

**Option 2**

If your door is intended to be a blueprint and you need to get a specific point, you can define a Scene Component in that Blueprint in the specific position you want it and then create a function that returns the World Location of that component. This is particularly useful if that position can change in time.

**Option 3**

Simply have a Vector parameter defining the offset of your given point in the actor's local space. You'll still need a function to translate that offset from Local to World or World to Local, highly depending on your approach.

With your given context, this is a way to interpret your situation.